# Why i cannot run python selenium script from my php codeigniter?

Tags: php, python, codeigniter, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm building a PHP web-based simple scraper. PHP gives a keyword to scrape, my python script does the thing and writes it on JSON file, then my PHP file read the JSON. but I have a problem, it is worked well on my IDE, but when moved to Codeigniter, it doesn't.

there are two problems:

1. The scraper script (using selenium) won't run
2. forbidden access (SOLVED by moving the directory)

the error message for forbidden access:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(http://localhost/scraper/application/controllers/scrap-result.json): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

> below work fine when running from IDE

script.php

```
$item= "thingtosearch";
$output = shell_exec('python C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium\crawler.py '.escapeshellarg($item).' '.escapeshellarg($item));
```

crawler.py

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
import json

url = "https://www.webtoscrape.com/search?%5Bkeywords%5D=" +sys.argv[1]
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'profile.managed_default_content_settings.images':2}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
snippets = {'python': [], 'text': [], 'php': [], 'js': []}


#scraping goes here


driver.quit()
myfile = open('scrap-result.json','w+')
json.dump(snippets['js'], 
sys.exit(1)
```

but when I move my code to Codeigniter, it doesn't

> below doesn't work

snippet of script-controller-codeigniter.php

```
$output = shell_exec('python C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium\crawler.py '.escapeshellarg($data['keyword']));
$filepath = base_url() ."application/controllers/scrap-result.json";
print($filepath); #to check if path is correct
$result= json_decode(file_get_contents( $filepath));
print_r($hasilscrape );
```

i dumped the $filepath(location for the json file) and is correct.

my OS is windows, I'm using XAMPP and all my code is in my local pc.

my question is:

1. what caused the selenium not running?
2. what caused forbidden access even though I run locally (SOLVED by moving the directory)

Comment: when you do file_get_contents use the filesystem path not the url since it's local. Also you should look into php selenium, Facebook makes a library available.

Comment: @pguardiario hi thank You for your response, as for this forbidden problem, I solved it by moving the JSON to projectroot/newfolder, before was inside projectroot/application/third_party.


for your suggestion I will look into php-webdriver by FB You suggested. I just have a question if You don't mind, have You tried to use it with any PHP framework? because I did't know this kind of problem would happen, and it would be good to know if php-webdriver is compatible with any framework